# Knockout.js very slowly foreach

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

I'm trying to create a simple markup with templates. Something like:

```
<div class="list" data-bind="template: {name: 'mytemplate', data: someData}"></div>

<script id="mytemplate">
  <div class="item" data-bind="text: someText"></div>
</script>
```

It works very nice, but if i need to render a lot of divs with this templates its going to be very slow. Knockout after creating each div adds it to the document. But, if i do something like this:

```
el = document.createElement("div");
applyBindings(myModel, el);

(div.list).innerHTML = el.innerHTML
```

It works much faster but is inconvenient.

Maybe Knockout has some built in feature for creating a group of element and after that adding this group to the document?

Comment: Can you post the JavaScript code that binds your template?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It sounds like KO is manipulating the DOM with each DIV you add. DOM traversal is expensive and will slow down the rendering of your page. There is an open issue for this under the KO Github: https://github.com/SteveSanderson/knockout/issues/248

In my opinion, Knockout is presently not up to the task of handling large foreach data sets. Performance on Chrome is decent (because Chrome is awesome), but pretty bad on Internet Explorer (and even worse on older IE): http://jsfiddle.net/StarcounterJack/FgSCw/

Instead of using Knockout, try a manual approach: create the DIVs in memory first and insert them into the DOM all at once. This is what you're doing in your second example with document.createElement(). With jQuery, you could do this:

```
var newDiv = $("<div>my new div</div>");
var newDiv2 = $("<div>my new div2</div>");
newDiv.append(newDiv2);
$('body').append(newDiv); //only this last step traverses the DOM
```

For templating, I prefer to use Mustache.js, load the templates using John Resig's `<head><script type="text/templates">` [template inclusion trick](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-micro-templating/) and take care of the rendering manually through my own JavaScript. You have more control over how the elements are rendered and can try different approaches when you run into performance problems like the one you have now.

Comment: Thats right, i want to create all elements in memory first, but i dont know how i can do that with KO) About my code, only what i can add its about my modelview function `function myModel() {someData : [...];}` Thats all my code)

Comment: DIV with class "list" already in the document, its some list, and i want to add some list items with using template.

Comment: Elliot, manually editing the DOM like this while using Knockout's binding will cause all sorts of issues. You are correct that KO must manipulate the DOM, but that is sort of what it does. Your solution will *break the page* if used with knockout.

Comment: @Tyrsius I'm suggesting that he not use Knockout at all, or if he does, keep it completely separate from the part of his page that requires rendering "lots of divs". KO isn't up to the task of quickly rendering hundreds of successive DOM elements on all browsers. I ran the jsFiddle example on IE7 and it locked my browser for about half a minute.

Comment: @ElliotB. Ok, that makes sense. The sentence starting "Try creating the DIVs in memory first" is a bit unclear that you mean "insted of using knockout." Do you think you could clarify your answer?

Comment: My page was made without using KO, but today i want to add some additional features, like dropdown lists. I think KO its overkill for me, at this moment, the Mustache.js more appropriate for my tasks)

Answer (score 3):

The best solution right now might be my [knockout-fast-foreach plugin](https://github.com/brianmhunt/knockout-fast-foreach).

It has `O(1)` inserts and deletes, among other features to make it notably fast (i.e. faster than one could easily do on your own).

It is a strong contender to replace the current foreach binding in KO 3.5 (or 3.6).

Comment: Thanks for this plugin. It makes rendering comparatively fast!